# For what purpose personal_access_tokens database table is made in Laravel 8.+

Tags: laravel-8

For what purpose personal_access_tokens database table is made in Laravel 8.+?

Here is ERD of this table:

[image]

And where is a tutorials to use it right way?

Comment: This link will help you 

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#personal-access-tokens

Comment: Hi, now I understand that it is system which can be used to get access to software without login with username and password. So I do not have an any use for this kind of feature on App I am developing right now. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the personal access token is mostly used to store tokens for the users who use your system via an API mostly for authentications you can create a toke using laravel sanctum.
you can read more about it in

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: Do you mean I can do with personal acccess tokens a system that can be used give access for an external App that come to integrated to my Laravel App?

Comment: yes. for example you can create an app that provides API. and give token to your users so they can use your APIs